# Form Calculator and display

Tags: forms, calculator

is there anyway at all that i can get the number of lessons chosen to be multiplied by the lesson type and then displayed as a total near the form? It would be far easier for people filling out the form to have an automated calculation rather than having to have to calculate it themselves.

```
  <h4>Lesson Form</h4>
          <form action="mailer.php" data-validate="parsley" method="post" >
          <p><strong>Full Name<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <input name="cf_name" data-required="true"  class="send" type="text" />
          <p><strong>Email Address<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <input name="cf_email" data-required="true" data-type="email" class="send" type="text" />
          <p><strong>Cellphone No.<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <input name="cf_cell" data-required="true" class="send" type="text" />

          <p><strong>Instrument Type<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <select name="cf_instrument" size="1" class="option" >
          <option value="Piano">Piano</option>
          <option value="Vocals">Vocals</option>
          <option value="Guitar">Guitar</option>
          <option value="Bass">Bass</option>
          <option value="Flute">Flute</option></select>

          <p><strong>Lesson Type<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <select name="cf_package_type" size="1" class="option">
          <option value="Beginner Lesson - R100">Beginner Lesson - R100</option>
          <option value="Advanced Lesson - R130">Advanced Lesson - R130</option>
          <option value="Professional Lesson - R160">Professional Lesson - R160</option></select>

          <p><strong>No. of Lessons<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
          <select id="number-of-lessons" name="cf_number" size="1" class="option" onchange='test()'>
          <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
          <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
          <option name="3" value="3">3</option>
          <option name="4" value="4">4</option></select>

          <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
             <p><strong>Lesson Date & Time<span class="red">*</span></strong></p>
                <p class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
          <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true" />
          <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true" /> to
          <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true" /></p>

          <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
                <p id="lesson-2" class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
          <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true"  />
          <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true"  /> to
          <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true"  /></p>

          <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
                <p id="lesson-3" class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
          <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true"  />
          <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true"  /> to
          <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true"  /></p>

          <script src="js/datepair.js"></script>
                <p id="lesson-4" class="datepair" data-language="javascript">
          <input type="text" name="cf_booking_date" class="date start" data-required="true"  />
          <input type="text" name="cf_start_time" class="time start" data-required="true"  /> to
          <input type="text" name="cf_end_time" class="time end" data-required="true"  /></p> 

           <!-- HIDDEN FIELD - HONEYPOT ANTI_SPAM -->
          <input id="website" class="using" name="website" type="text"  />
          <!-- END -->
          <input name="Submit" class="submit" value="Book Now" type="submit" /></form>
```

Would you so great if you could help me with this!

Comment: you'll have to use a script for this one..

Comment: I figured that much :) - anyone got any good scripts for this type of code?

Comment: Here's the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/h3hkY/. I basically just need an automated calculation to appear at the bottom of the form based on the package type chosen multiplied by the number of lessons chosen.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/Y6b3b/) a solution using Javascript.

explanation:
every time the option changes, I'm recalculating the multiplication of the chosen values.

**HTML** (simplified version of what you have. *Notice how I changed the value of your options.*)

```
<select id="lesson-type" onchange='calculate()'>
    <option value="100">Beginner Lesson - R100</option>
    <option value="130">Advanced Lesson - R130</option>
    <option value="160">Professional Lesson - R160</option>
</select>

<select id="number-of-lessons" onchange='calculate()'>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<label id="result"></label>
```

**JS:**

```
function calculate() {
    var l_type = document.getElementById("lesson-type").value;
    var num_lessons = document.getElementById("number-of-lessons").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = l_type * num_lessons;
}
```

**Edit:**
in this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/Y6b3b/1/) I also call the function once the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create simple web calculator with Javascript I would recommend you to take a look at “Appizy”.

It converts instantly a spreadsheet into a standalone web calculation tool in HTML+CSS+JAVASCRIPT. You don’t need to hardcode the whole interface and calculation formulas!

Just create your working calculator with Open- or LibreOffice and then use Appizy.

I hope it can help. Best,
Nicolas